# Timespan not working with in memory LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I was under the impression that when using in memory LINQ as below that TimeSpan is able to be used. If this is not the case how do I convert TimeSpan to date then? Note I believe entities in an in memory list.

```
var charterRequestDtoIds = from e in entities.Where(e => e.ClientId == clientId
                                        && e.Status != TrackingState.Void
                                        && DateTime.Now < DbFunctions.AddDays(e.CreatedAt, e.BiddingToCloseIn.Days + 30))
                                    select(e.Id);
```

The Error:

> System.NotSupportedException: The specified type member 'BiddingToCloseIn' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: What is entities ? An in-memory list ? or some IQueryable ?

Comment: In memory list I believe

Comment: Where is the code using `TimeSpan` and what's the error? And what _I believe_ should mean?

Comment: Alright question updated with more information

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error is because `BiddingToCloseIn.Days` or `BiddingToCloseIn` are not database columns for the entity in question. Try converting the upper portion of the where clause to a list using `ToList` and then applying another `where` to the list.

Comment: why `DbFunctions` is used with in memory list?

Comment: @AlekseyL. because it is not In-Memory. The question is just misleading.